# Erase color lines Drawn on image Canvas HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have one canvas with image, on that i have drawn one rectangle with red color.Now i want to clear that red color rectangle on touch event of user, My problem is it clears image too. It is not showing image.

Using code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" width="220" height="277" src="img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
     ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
     ctx.clearRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My Result is:
[image]

What i expect :[image]

Also, I have checked this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArtBIT/WUXDb/1/) , Now How can I fill color on that removed area again.

Comment: I honestly recommend you to read about canvas, pixels, buffers and general computer graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create yourself a rect not a fillRect, once you have created your rect you then draw your image, and the image you supply will be used to fill in the rect you drew

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/308tv9dL/3/

javascript

```
render = function () {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");

    ctx.rect(25, 25, 150, 150);
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 200);
}

render();
```

Comment: What If I want to fill color on touch of user after clearing that area using clear
Rect ?

Comment: There is a `context.rect()` method... what is important in your snippet is the `clip()` method that you don't even mentioned. your path is closed, no need for `closePath()`, `context.save()` saves the actual properties of the context (fillColor, matrixTransformations, lineWidth etc.) here you don't modify any of these properties (beginPath is not one of them), and thus is does nothing else than calling a consumptive method for free and finally, it's `setInterval( func, time )` ;  `render` will be called only once when the parser will try to get a number from it...

Comment: the `setInterval` is just there to render, to be honest I can remove it, also if you have a better answer then post it.

Comment: No, I don't have time rn to write a proper answer, there are a lot of possible ways to do it, and it would take me too much time to explain them all to OP, maybe later. We're here to provide good answers and I am trying to make yours (which is one of the best solution) better, by removing all the craps you putted around the actual solution : `ctx.beginPath()` `ctx.rect()`, `ctx.clip()`. You are doing big mistakes in this code, and we don't need it on the website.

Comment: @Kaiido well I have just updated my code, I hope you approve.

Comment: Your code is better but your heading answer doesn't reflect it anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  var cOver = document.getElementById("myCanvasOver");
    var overtx = cOver .getContext("2d");
     overtx .fillStyle = "red";
    overtx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);
    overtx.clearRect(20, 20, 100, 50);
}
```

```html
<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<div style='position:relative;height:300px;width:250px;'>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="300"
style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<canvas id="myCanvasOver" width="250" height="300"
style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;">
</canvas>
</div>
```